# lightbox onclick change src then change back

Tags: javascript, onclick, materialize, lightbox

I am using Materialize CSS and have the "Material Box" which is a lightbox plugin. I want all of the thumbnails to be the same size. When clicked I want the full photo to load.

I am using `onclick` to change the src. How do I change it back to the thumbnail when the large photo closes (either with a click or the escape key)?

```
<div class="col s6 m3">
    <img class="materialboxed responsive-img" src="images/thumb1.jpg" onclick='this.src="images/photo1"'>              
</div>
```

Material Box Javascript

```
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.materialboxed');
        var options = {}
        var instances = M.Materialbox.init(elems, options);
      });

      // Or with jQuery

      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.materialboxed').materialbox();
      });
```

Materializecss.com - https://materializecss.com/media.html

I haven't found an easy other way of achieving the lightbox effect with cropped square thumbnails. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one implementation of what you want, keeping track of the image click state.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.materialboxed').materialbox();

    // Image sources
    const srcThumb = '/images/thumb1.jpg'
    const srcPhoto = '/images/photo1.jpg'

    // Click state
    var clicked = false

    // Get image element and bind click event
    const img = $('.materialboxed')
    img.on('click', function() {
        img.attr('src', clicked ? srcPhoto : srcThumb)
        clicked = !clicked
    })

});
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to rely on `onclick` in this case.
Materialize is already binding onclick for those images.
And it provides the following native methods we can use for doing exactly what you want using pure JS (no jQuery):

> onOpenStart Function null Callback function called before materialbox is opened.

> onCloseEnd Function null Callback function called after materialbox is closed.

In this example below, we assume there is a normal materialboxed photo gallery containing thumbnails named `thumb_whatever.jpg`, for example. But we're also serving the original sized photo named `whatever.jpg` in the same directory.

Then we're changing `src` attribute dynamically removing the `thumb_` prefix to get the original image, which in this case will be imediately lightboxed by materialize.

And after closing the lightbox, the `src` attribute is being set back again without the `thumb_` prefix.

We do that while initializing Materialbox:

```
// Initializing Materialbox
const mb = document.querySelectorAll('.materialboxed')
M.Materialbox.init(mb, {
  onOpenStart: (el) => {
    var src = el.getAttribute('src') // get the src
    var path = src.substring(0,src.lastIndexOf('/')) // get the path from the src
    var fileName = src.substring(src.lastIndexOf('/')).replace('thumb_','') // get the filename and removes 'thumb_' prefix
    var newSrc = path+fileName // re-assemble without the 'thumb_' prefix

    el.setAttribute('src', newSrc)
  },
  onCloseEnd: (el) => {
    var src = el.getAttribute('src') // get the src
    var path = src.substring(0,src.lastIndexOf('/')) // get the path from the src
    var fileName = src.substring(src.lastIndexOf('/')).replace('/', '/thumb_') // get the filename and adds 'thumb_' prefix
    var newSrc = path+fileName // re-assemble with the 'thumb_' prefix
    
    el.setAttribute('src', newSrc)
  }
})
```

This solution is also working like a charm for me, crossplatform.